# PHP redirection problem using header("location:URL ")

Tags: php

I am working on a file `help.php` in directory `help`.I want to redirect user with the help of that `help.php` file to `help.php/?step=2`. For this I used code

```
header('location : help.php/?step=2');
```

But, instead of redirecting to `help.php/?step=2` it is redirecting to `help.php/help.php/?step=2`. What is problem here?

Comment: remove the `/` and do `header('location : help.php?step=2');`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the location path will be relative to your current path if you don't have a preceding slash. That is, a starting page `/example.php` and a `location` header of `other.php` will produce `/example.php/other.php`. In order to fix this, add the preceding slash in your `location` header:

```
header('location : /help.php?step=2');
```

Please look into the concept of relative vs. absolute paths for more information on this subject.

Comment: talking about my url it is `localhost/help/help.php` and I want to redirect to `localhost/help/help.php/?step=2`. When I try your code it just redirect me to `localhost/help.php/?step=2`.

Comment: You never mentioned this in your original question. The solution is simple: you only need to update that line of code to `header('location : /help/help.php?step=2');`.